# Kubernetes Configmap data format

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, yaml, configmap, spring-properties

I'm writing a K8s configmap for my Spring Boot application.
This is my application.yaml file:

```
app:
config:
    paths:
        - id: a
          uri: http://localhost:8080
          args:
            - x=1
            - y=2

        - id: b
          uri: http://localhost:8081
          args:
            - x=3
            - y=4
```

I tried to convert it into Kubernetes configmap as below (I followed this document https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Relaxed-Binding-2.0):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
    name: my-configmap
data:
    app.config.paths_0_id: a
    app.config.paths_0_uri: "http://a-service"
    app.config.paths_0_args_0_: "x=1"
    app.config.paths_0_args_1_: "y=2"

    app.config.paths_1_id: b
    app.config.paths_1_uri: "http://b-service"
    app.config.paths_1_args_0_: "x=3"
    app.config.paths_1_args_1_: "y=4"
```

And in the deployment file I defined configmap:

```
       ...
       envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              my-configmap
       ...
```

But when I deployed my application, it was not working, the configmap did not override the application.yaml, for example: the first **uri** of **app.config.paths** still is **http://localhost:8080** not **http://a-service**.

So anyone has experience with that, please help me! How can I define an array in K8S configmap?

Thanks

Comment: In config-maps you cannot use collections,  only key/values. Try to change the collections `foo.bar['baz']: value1` to ` foo: value or foo: "value"`

Comment: Try to follow the whole "environment variable thing". For example, try with `APP_CONFIG_PATHS_0_ID` as I don't think you can mix dots with underscores in this particular situation. With this said, I think the best option when you have a list in the configuration, is to inject the ConfigMap as a file

Comment: I have tried `APP_CONFIG_PATHS_0_ID` and it worked well, thank you!